# Interpolation on Sobolev space on $[0, 1]^d$ over finite meshes

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory

Let $\Omega = [0, 1]^d$ and suppose that $f \colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ lies in order $m > d/2$ Sobolev space; i.e.,
$$
\|f\|_{H^m(\Omega)}^2 = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq m} \|D^\alpha f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 < \infty.
$$
Let $x_1, \dots, x_n\in \Omega$ and define the distance
$$
h \equiv h_\Omega(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \sup_{y \in \Omega} \min_{i = 1, \dots, n} |y - x_i|, 
$$
where above $|\cdot|$ denotes the usual Euclidean norm on $[0, 1]^d$.

We can then consider the minimum Sobolev norm interpolant:
$$
s_{m, \Omega}(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 
\mathrm{argmin}_{g \in L^2(\Omega)} \Big\{\|g\|_{H^m(\Omega)} : g(x_i) = f(x_i), ~~\mbox{for}~i = 1,\dots n\Big\}
$$

I have seen the following theorem quoted in various papers/sources (Matveev, the book by Anatoly Yu. Bezhaev, Vladimir A. Vasilenko, etc.), but none containing a full proof:

> **Theorem:** Suppose that $f \in H^m(\Omega)$ where $\Omega = [0, 1]^d$ and $m > d/2$. Let $x_1, \dots, x_n \in \Omega$ and let $\widehat{f}$ denote the interpolant $s_{m, \Omega}(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. Then there exists a constant $C$ depending only on $\Omega, m$ such that $$
> \|f - \widehat{f}\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C~ h^{m}~\|f\|_{H^m(\Omega)}.
> $$

Is there any source (in English) which provides a full (ideally self-contained) proof of this result?

Comment: To give some references where this type of claim is made: equation (4.75) in the book Variational Theory of Splines (Bezhaev, Vasilenko). Also seems to be a central result of the paper by J. Douchon [Analyse numérique, Volume 12 (1978) no. 4, pp. 325-334]. Although this paper is written in French and a bit difficult for me to check all the details.